# How can I escape % characters in YAML?

Tags: ruby, yaml

How can I escape % characters in YAML?

Comment: put the string it in double quotes: `option: "% some string"`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try `%%` it might work to escape.

Answer (score 15):

put the string it in double quotes:
`"%{var} some string"`

Answer (score 4):

If in doubt, try converting a string to yaml in IRB

```
C:\Documents and Settings\a.grimm>irb
irb(main):001:0> require "yaml"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> "I'm giving it 110%!".to_yaml
=> "--- I'm giving it 110%!\n"
irb(main):003:0> exit
```