# How can I escape a $ dollar sign in a docker compose file?

Tags: escaping, docker-compose

I have a YAML scalar that is throwing the following error when I try to evaluate my `docker-compose.yml` file:

> ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in
>   service "time_service": "${Time.now}"

YAML:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  time_service:
    build: "."
    environment:
      TIME: "${Time.now}"
```

How can I maintain the same string output as written, but avoid having the docker-compose interpret it as faulty string interpolation?

Comment: It is not the YAML parser that is interpreting that string. YAML doesn't know about `${}`. Interpreting is done by `docker-compose` and that is written in Python, so the tag ruby was inappropriate as well.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

> You can use a `$$` (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs
> a literal dollar sign.

You are hitting the `docker-compose` variable substitution, which is well documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#variable-substitution):

> Both `$VARIABLE` and `${VARIABLE}` syntax are supported. Extended shell-style features, such as `${VARIABLE-default}` and `${VARIABLE/foo/bar}`, are not supported.
>
> You can use a `$$` (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a value, so a `$$` allows you to refer to environment variables that you don’t want processed by Compose.

`docker-compose` is written in Python, as you see on [github](https://github.com/docker/compose), the doubling mechanism to get the original meaning of special characters can be found in many programs, I needed to use this myself, while programming, as far back in 1984.

Comment: what is the functional difference between the variable with and without the curly braces? `$VARIABLE` vs `${VARIABLE}`?

Comment: If the `$VARIABLE` is directly followed alphabetic character (`$VARIABLEX`, you'll have to use the more verbose `${VARIABLE}X`

Comment: Note that `${VARIABLE-default}` *"extended shell-style feature"* is now supported (but still not `${VARIABLE/foo/bar}`) and that **Docker Compose V2** is no longer written in **Python** but in **Go**.

Answer (score 50):

Found the answer by copying the suggestion for `%` characters in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051090/how-can-i-escape-characters-in-yaml)

It requires a double dollar sign `$$`.

So I needed `"$${Time.now}"`, which evaluates to `"${Time.now}"`