# How to parameterize dockerfile with .env?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pytest

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897503/docker-compose-invalid-interpolation-format-for-environment-option-in-service) does not solve my problem, as I have no escaping issues.

I have a `rabbit.env`:

```
NETWORK_NAME=uv_atp_network
```

and a dockerfile

```
version: '2.3'
networks:
  atp:
    name: $NETWORK_NAME
    external: true
services:
    rabbitmq_local:
        image: 'rabbitmq:3.6-management-alpine'
        ports:
          - '5672:5672'
          - '15672:15672'
        networks:
          - $NETWORK_NAME
```

Both in the same folder.

When running

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("network",)
def test_rabbit_up(client, session_scoped_container_getter):
    pass
```

which calls `docker-compose up` [behind the scenes](https://github.com/pytest-docker-compose/pytest-docker-compose#:%7E:text=This%20package%20contains%20a%20pytest,down%20after%20each%20test%20ends.), I am getting

`Service "rabbitmq_local" uses an undefined network ""`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The default file loaded to read environment values is `.env`, not `whatever.env`. If you want to use an alternate non-default environment file, you need to pass its path in a `--env-file` option to `docker-compose`. See `docker-compose --help` and https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Compose file, you've named the network `atp`

```yaml
networks:
  atp: # <-- you need this name
    settings: don't matter to this naming question
```

and so you need to use that name when you refer to it in a container definition

```yaml
services:
  rabbitmq_local:
    networks:
      - atp # <-- the Compose file name of the network
```

Since this name is local to the Compose file, you can choose any name you want.  In particular, you're allowed to name the network `default`, which [reconfigures the default network Compose creates](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network); if you do this, you don't need to mention it for individual services.

```yaml
networks:
  default: { external: true, name: $NETWORK_NAME }
services:
  rabbitmq_local:
    # no networks:, Compose will provide `networks: [default]` for you
```

Comment: Could I also do `networks:
  $NETWORK_NAME: external: true`? and then refer to it with `services: service_name: networks: $NETWORK_NAME`?

Comment: That's not clear in the documentation, but it also doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: I am getting `compose.config.errors.ConfigurationError: Network default declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create default` and try again.` when using as proposed here. It doesn't seem to distinguish that default is the network name. Docker 1.24

Comment: Is the `NETWORK_NAME` environment variable actually set?

Comment: I also want to parameterize ports. doing `ports: - ${RABBIT_PORT}:5672` gives `docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.rabbitmq_local.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object`. Any ideas?

Comment: Using ` - ${RABBIT_PORT:?unspecified_rabbit_port}:5672` I am getting the error, meaning it is actually not specified, same as `NETWORK_NAME`. How to debug why that happens? They do appear in the `.env`

Comment: Ok this works, but I can't find a way to parameterize a non-default name. It doesn't know the parameterized network exists, even though it does. Probably a syntax fail by me. Do you know how to do that?