# Add environment variable as regex in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to add environment variable that has regex value

```
version: "2.3"
services:
    ...
  php:
    ...
    environment:
      - "CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$"
```

when run `docker-compose up`

it gives me that error:
`ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "php": "CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$"`

I have played around and removed `$`, it works fine but want to keep it.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I escape a $ dollar sign in a docker compose file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40619582/how-can-i-escape-a-dollar-sign-in-a-docker-compose-file)

Answer (score 0):

It tries to expand your dollar sign. Try using `\$` instead of `$` or take value in single quotes which prevent macro expansion.

Comment: It gives me another error `ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a double-quoted scalar
  in "/path/docker-compose.development.yml", line 55, column 9`

Comment: Tried put this value into `.env` file?

Comment: I gonna use this solution for now however it's not the best solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `$$` to escape the dollar (`$`) symbols.

```
version: "2.3"
services:
    ...
  php:
    ...
    environment:
      - "CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://localhost(:[0-9]+)?$$'
```

See variable substitution in the [docker-compose doc (v2)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#variable-substitution)