# Treafik addPrefix/replacePathRegex

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to set up geoserver and traefik with docker, but having an issue with the paths.

Geoserver's main entrypoint is at `/geoserver`, but I want to make it accessible at the root path of my domain, let's say `example.com`. Here's the `docker-compose` file I put together:

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --providers=docker
      - --providers.docker.network=geoserver_web
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=websecure
      # - --api.dashboard=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.email=admin@example.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.storage=acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
  
  geoserver:
    image: oscarfonts/geoserver:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
      - traefik.http.middlewares.geoserver.replacepathregex.regex=(.*)
      - traefik.http.middlewares.geoserver.replacepathregex.replacement=/geoserver/$$1

networks:
  web:
```

After going through the [traefik docs](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/replacepathregex/#replacepathregex), I thought using `replacepathregex` on geoserver service should prepend `/geoserver` to the paths for all the requests passed to geoserver and should make the service available at `example.com`, instead of `example.com/geoserver`, but it didn't work.

I also tried [`addPrefix`](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/addprefix/#add-prefix), but that didn't work either.

Is my configuration incorrect?
Or my understanding of what those middlewares do?
Is there a way to configure my service to be accessible at `example.com`, instead of `example.com/geoserver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out the issue was my traefik config! I needed to add the middleware to the geoserver router. Here's the updated `docker-compose.yml` (I went with `addprefix` instead of `replacepathregex` because the latter was an overkill):

```
version: "3"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:2.4
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    command:
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --providers=docker
      - --providers.docker.network=geoserver_web
      - --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.to=websecure
      - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entrypoint.scheme=websecure
      # - --api.dashboard=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.email=admin@example.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.storage=acme.json
      - --certificatesresolvers.lets-encrypt.acme.tlschallenge=true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
  
  geoserver:
    image: oscarfonts/geoserver:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - traefik.http.middlewares.add-geoserver-prefix.addprefix.prefix=/geoserver
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.rule=Host(`example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt
      - traefik.http.routers.geoserver.middlewares=add-geoserver-prefix@docker

networks:
  web:
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [ReplacePathRegex: Configuration Examples](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/replacepathregex/), the Docker tab, it mentions as the following example: -

```yaml
# Replace path with regex
labels:
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.regex=^/foo/(.*)"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.test-replacepathregex.replacepathregex.replacement=/bar/$$1"
```

Together with the following quoting

> Regular expressions and replacements can be tested using online tools such as [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mWU9p-wk2ru) or [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/58sIgx/2).

I use the Regex101 to test and ensure the sample configuration above and extend so that we achieve our requirement as the following scenarios.

##### Test case 1

- Regular Expression: `/foo/(.*)` (Note: there is no leading caret `^` here)
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/foo/api`
- Substitution: `/bar/$1` (Note: there is a single dollar sing `$` here, explain later)
- The result: `https://my.domain.com/bar/api`

##### Test case 2

- Regular Expression: `/foo/(.*)`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/foo/api`
- Substitution: `/$1`
- The result: `https://my.domain.com/api`

#### Test case 3: The geoserver round 1

- Regular Expression: `(.*)/(.*)`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/api`
- Substitution: `$1/geoserver/$2`
- The result: `https://my.domain.com/geoserver/api`

#### Test case 4: The geoserver round 2

- Regular Expression: `(.*)/(.*)`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/api`
- Substitution: `/geoserver/$2`
- The result: `/geoserver/api`

###### Sidebar 1: Why do we need double dollar sing (`$$`) ?

Because the **docker-compose** provides the *variable substitution*, in a form of `$VARIABLE` and `${VARIABLE}`, then the dollar sign is a `key word / reserved word` which we have to *escape* it and cause us to use dollar sing (`$$`) within the `docker-compose.yml`. Please refer to the **StackOverflow** [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40619582/813999) and [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40621373/813999) for further information.

###### Sidebar 2: The leading caret (`^`)

After trial-and-error for a while, I realize that there is a bit different as the Traefik require the leading caret while the Regex101 does not. Up until now, I still have no idea why it is and remember that way :D

##### Summarize

To achieve our requirement by following the test case 4, the **docker-compose** *label* , should be as the following example

```yaml
labels:
  - traefik.http.middlewares.geoserver.replacepathregex.regex=^(.*)/(.*) # <-- the leading caret
  - traefik.http.middlewares.geoserver.replacepathregex.replacement=/geoserver/$$2
```

#### Edit 1

#### Test case 5: The geoserver round 3

- Regular Expression: `^(.*:)//([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+)(:[0-9]+)?/(.*)$`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/path`

  - Substitution: `/geoserver/$4`
  - The result: `/geoserver/path`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/path/to`

  - Substitution: `/geoserver/$4`
  - The result: `/geoserver/path/to`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/path/to/api`

  - Substitution: `/geoserver/$4`
  - The result: `/geoserver/path/to/api`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/path/to/api?key=value`

  - Substitution: `/geoserver/$4`
  - The result: `/geoserver/path/to/api?key=value`
- Test String: `https://my.domain.com/path/to/api?key=value&anotherkey=anothervalue`

  - Substitution: `/geoserver/$4`
  - The result: `/geoserver/path/to/api?key=value&anotherkey=anothervalue`

##### Summarize

To achieve our requirement by following the test case 5, the **docker-compose** *label* , should be as the following example

```yaml
labels:
  - traefik.http.middlewares.geoserver.replacepathregex.regex=^(.*:)//([A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+)(:[0-9]+)?/(.*)$$ # <-- the leading caret and double dollar sign at the end
  - traefik.http.middlewares.geoserver.replacepathregex.replacement=/geoserver/$$4
```

Comment: Thanks, @charlee-chitsuk, but your answer doesn't work. The final suggested pattern, i.e. `(.*)(.*)`, catches everything before the last slash, and then in the replacement pattern you're dropping everything before it (the first capture group) and replacing it with `/geoserver`, but that's not the objective (also it didn't work as described in the answer). The goal is to prepend `/geoserver` to whatever request we pass to `geoserver` service.

Comment: Please look at my edit 1, the test case 5.

Comment: I spent more time on this, and turned out the issue wasn't the regex or the syntax of `replacepathregex` or `addprefix` middlewares, but attaching them to the geoserver router. See my own answer for the updated `docker-compose.yml`.